# I don't understand this paper's proof of the rank and nullity theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I stumbled upon the paper "A Note on the Equality of the Column and Row Rank of a Matrix" (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1080/0025570X.1995.11996337)

I will skip right to the part I don't understand, note that from previous paragraphs $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_r$ forms a basis for the row space of matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

> "Let $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k$ form a basis for the null space of $\mathbf A$. Since the row space of $\mathbf{A}$ and the null space of $\mathbf{A}$ intersect trivially, it follows that the set {$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_r, y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k$} is linearly independent. Further, if $z$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\mathbf{A}z$ is in the column space of $\mathbf{A}$ and hence expressible as a linear combination of basis elements. Thus, we can write $\mathbf{A}z = \sum_{j=1}^r d_j\mathbf{A}x_j$, for scalars $d_j$. But then the vector $z = \sum_{j=1}^r d_jx_j$ is in the null space of $\mathbf{A}$ and can be written as a linear combination of $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k$. Thus $z$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in the set {$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_r, y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k$ }  and this set forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. A dimension count yields $r + k = n$, giving the rank and nullity theorem without use of the echelon form."

I don't understand the reasoning used to conclude that $z$ is in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$, from my reading $z$ is some arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that could be in the null space just as it could be in the row space or even not be in either space, and even if it was the case that $z$ is in the null space in then goes on to say that  $z$ is a linear combination of basis vectors from both the null and row space which would contradict $z$ being in the null space (unless we use scalars $0$ for all row space basis vectors)

Comment: That seems to be a typo in that paper. But I cannot access it so I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a typo; the equality sign in "$z = \sum_{j=1}^r d_jx_j$" should be a minus sign.

Comment: Actually, it is correct both in the scan at https://sci-hub.se/https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1995.11996337 and in the JSTOR scan https://www.ime.usp.br/~oliveira/POSTOMACKIW.pdf .

Comment: However, I think the paper is wrong at a different point: The claim that "the general structure of the arguments here can then be carried over to arbitrary fields" doesn't seem to hold, as the arguments rely on "only the zero vector is orthogonal to itself".

Comment: oh, indeed i mistakenly read the minus sign as equality and carried it over in my transcription (silly me), my apologies and thank you all for your time